# sql oracle nested table

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE product_type AS OBJECT (
    product_id NUMBER,
    product_name VARCHAR2(100),
    category_name VARCHAR2(100),
    producttypes VarcharList,
    list_price VARCHAR2(100)
);


--Type PRODUCT_TYPE compiled

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_item_type AS OBJECT (
    days_to_process NUMBER,
    price NUMBER,
    cost NUMBER(10),
    channel VARCHAR2(100),
    product product_type
);

--Type ORDER_ITEM_TYPE compiled

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_items_table AS TABLE OF order_item_type;

--Type ORDER_ITEMS_TABLE compiled

CREATE TABLE ordersv3 (
    order_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id NUMBER,
    order_items order_items_table 
) NESTED TABLE order_items STORE AS order_items_ntttt;



/*CREATE TABLE ordersv3 (
    order_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id NUMBER,
    order_items order_items_table 
) NESTED TABLE order_items STORE AS order_items_ntttt;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE ordersv3 (
    order_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id NUMBER,
    order_items order_items_table 
) NESTED TABLE order_items STORE AS order_items_ntttt
Error report -
ORA-02320: failure in creating storage table for nested table column ORDER_ITEMS
ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute
02320. 00000 -  "failure in creating storage table for nested table column %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while creating the storage table for the
           specified nested table column.*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You reported error on `CREATE TABLE ordersv3`, but - it is OK. What's wrong (in my database) is unknown type `varcharlist` in `create type product_type` (the first statement you posted) so I changed it to `sys.odcivarchar2list`; don't know whether that's what you wanted, but it *looks like* the one you posted.

If you ran that code as as script, note that you should have terminated all `create type` statements with a slash; otherwise, you'll get an error.

Statement 1:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE product_type AS OBJECT (
  2      product_id    NUMBER,
  3      product_name  VARCHAR2(100),
  4      category_name VARCHAR2(100),
  5      producttypes  sys.odcivarchar2list,
  6      list_price    VARCHAR2(100)
  7  );
  8  /

Type created.
```

Statement 2:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_item_type AS OBJECT (
  2      days_to_process NUMBER,
  3      price           NUMBER,
  4      cost            NUMBER(10),
  5      channel         VARCHAR2(100),
  6      product         product_type
  7  );
  8  /

Type created.
```

Statement 3:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_items_table AS
  2      TABLE OF order_item_type;
  3  /

Type created.
```

Statement 4, the one you reported to be wrong:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE ordersv3 (
  2      order_id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  3      customer_id NUMBER,
  4      order_items order_items_table
  5  )
  6  NESTED TABLE order_items STORE AS order_items_ntttt;

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ! I have created the VarcharList in my database is ok! I have the problem with the nested table but you tell me that it works perfectly in your db .. strange...

Comment: Which Oracle database version do you use? Mine is 21cXE, but I've just tested it on fiddle on 11gR2 - no errors either (see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/bJ2eRH8m).

Comment: i changed the lines VarcharList to producttypes  sys.odcivarchar2list and now it works to my db . I think the error was that I had created CREATE TYPE VarcharList AS TABLE OF VARCHAR(50); and somehow this was the error. I think that I had to NEST this table too ! If you have any ideas what I did wrong I would appreciate it. I have lost 2 days in this error -.-